# Server send event not working in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, events, server-sent-events

```
var source = new EventSource(CC_JSURL+"api_calls/quickbox/sse");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        su_oncall.checkStatus(JSON.parse(event.data));
    };
```

I have used this code for server sent event, it is working fine in chrome but in Firefox it is not working.

Comment: What does the network tab over in Firebug show? E.g. do you see the connection get made? (Also worth saying which OS, which browser versions, and if any proxies are involved.)

Comment: In the network tab some time it is showing the event triggering some times not triggering, but in chrome it is working fine.